# Is there a better way to do this (Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset with 5 main categories and 26 subcodes. Each item falls under any one or more of the 5 categories and is assigned ~1-6 of the subcodes.

I'm taking the few thousand entries and breaking it down as shown below in the pictures.

[image: Data Table]

[image: Data Counts]

Right now I am using filters to only show the items that have an "x" in the right columns and taking that data to a different tab where I use the `=SUM(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,"text","")))/LEN("text")` to pull out a count of each subcode from column G. I'm mainly wondering if there's a quicker way to get around having to manually do the filter for each category combination.

Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you considered countifs(), and just count if the code matches and has an x? No need to pull out at all just refence the primary data.